# Remove text from string/url

Tags: php, regex

i have many urls(string):

```
        $one = 'http://www.site.com/first/1/two/2/three/3/number/342';
        $two = '/first/1/two/2/number/32';
        $three = 'site.com/first/1/three/3/number/7';
        $four = 'http://www.site.com/first/13/two/2/three/33/number/33/four/23';
```

how can i remove for this variables **/number/x** with PHP?
for my examples should be:

```
    $one = 'http://www.site.com/first/1/two/2/three/3';
    $two = '/first/1/two/2';
    $three = 'site.com/first/1/three/3';
    $four = 'http://www.site.com/first/13/two/2/three/33/four/23';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$one = 'http://www.site.com/first/1/two/2/number/33/three/3';
$one = preg_replace('/\/number\/\d+/', '', $one);
echo $one;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following pattern:

```
'@/number/[0-9]{1,}@i'
```

**The reasons are:**

1. The `i` modifier will catch urls like '/NumBer/42'
2. Using `@` to delimit the pattern makes for a much more readable pattern and mitigates the need to escape slashes (e.g. `\/\d+`)
3. While `[0-9]{1,}` is more verbose than `\d+`, it has the added benefit of being much more intention revealing.

**Below is a demo of it's usage:**

```
<?php

$urls[] = 'http://www.site.com/first/1/two/2/three/3/number/342';
$urls[] = '/first/1/two/2/number/32';
$urls[] = 'site.com/first/1/three/3/number/7';
$urls[] = 'http://www.site.com/first/13/two/2/three/33/number/33/four/23';
$urls[] = '/first/1/Number/55/two/2/number/32';

$actual = array_map(function($url){
  return preg_replace('@/number/[0-9]{1,}@i', '', $url);
}, $urls);

$expected = array(
  'http://www.site.com/first/1/two/2/three/3',
  '/first/1/two/2',
  'site.com/first/1/three/3',
  'http://www.site.com/first/13/two/2/three/33/four/23',
  '/first/1/two/2'
);

assert($expected === $actual); // true
```